# using mRender with datatables and css is not processing?

Tags: datatables

I am using mRender to add checkboxes in the first column of the tbody... the correct css styling is being applied, but they are not stylized when I view the table. I can only assume this is because I am using mRender to add these values in, however, if I do other css like changing color of text it works fine.  I have no problem with the checkbox in the thead being properly styled, but this is included by default with the html. Ideas?

the html:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="#sample_1 .checkboxes" /></th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

the js:

```
$('#sample_1').dataTable({
//start my code
"bProcessing": true,
"bServerSide": true,
"sAjaxSource": "/assets/data-tables/test-normal.php",
//end my code
"aLengthMenu": [
    [5, 15, 20, -1],
    [5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
],
"aoColumnDefs": [ {
    "aTargets": [ 0 ],
    "bSortable": false,
    "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="'+data+'" />';
    }
} ],
// set the initial value
"iDisplayLength": 5,
"sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
"oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sPrevious": "Prev",
        "sNext": "Next"
    }
},
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to use :

```
"fnInitComplete": function() {
    $(".checkboxes").uniform();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the mData portion

In aoColumns, not aoColumnDefs, use the following

```
{ "mData": null , // can use null, the numeric array number, or assoc array string
     "mRender" : function ( data, type, full ) { 
        return '<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="'+data+'" />'}
      },
```

Comment: That doesn't solve it either.  My code above works exactly as expected, but for some reason there is no styling on the checkboxes inside the tbody.  Using firebug the json is correct, output is correct, css is correct.  I can actually change it to return '<span class="text-danger">'+data+'</span>'; and it displays the id in red text as it should.  No dice on the checkbox styling though.

Comment: provide a jsfiddle of your code, i'll be glad to help figure it out, its something small that i can't tell from the code posted so far